# How to set tinymce content dynamically

Tags: jquery, tinymce-4

I am trying to change content of tinymce editor dynamically.
even this steps is not working. Actually i want to put contents on ajax success, But since it is not working i cant continue.

I am getting Type error tinemce.get() is null and tinymce.activeEditor is null erros

```
<textarea style="height:700px" name="proposal" id="proposal" >
                        hi
</textarea>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
                        tinymce.init({
                          selector: "#proposal",
                          height: 250,
                          theme: "modern",
                          plugins: [
                            "autoresize advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
                            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
                            "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
                            "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools codesample toc"
                          ],
                          toolbar1: "undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | codesample",
                          image_advtab: true,
                          content_css: [
                            "https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                          ], 


                        });
                        var content = "<p>Hello World </p>";
                        tinyMCE.get("proposal").setContent(content);//not working
                        tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(content);//not working

                    });

<script>
```

Answer (score 6):

In Tinymce 4 you can try it:

```
// Sets the HTML contents of the activeEditor editor
tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('<span>some</span> html');

// Sets the raw contents of the activeEditor editor
tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('<span>some</span> html', {format: 'raw'});

// Sets the content of a specific editor (my_editor in this example)
tinymce.get('my_editor').setContent(data);

// Sets the bbcode contents of the activeEditor editor if the bbcode plugin was added
tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('[b]some[/b] html', {format: 'bbcode'});
```

Read more via [Tinymce](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#setcontent)

Answer (score 1):

Your calls to `tinyMCE.get("proposal")` and `tinyMCE.activeEditor` are likely happening before the editor is actually instantiated.  The TinyMCE `init()` method takes time to complete but you are calling these two methods directly after the `init()` so the editor is probably not yet initialized.

The editor has an `init` event you can use to know when the editor is fully initialized and then you can use the editor APIs.  You can put something like this in your TinyMCE configuration:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "#proposal",
    ...
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('init', function () {
            var content = "<p>Hello World </p>";
            editor.setContent(content);
        });
    }  
});
```

Comment: Thanks you....The answer is close.but will it work on outside the init? as i mentioned in my question i want to use it in an ajax success

Comment: Indeed you can - just know that you cannot call any TinyMCE APIs until the editor is fully loaded.  Your example does not show any AJAX calls so my answer was tailored to your example.  You can use the `init` to trigger an AJAX call to fetch data or you can fetch data in other ways - just make sure the editor is initialized before you try to use its APIs.